# SQL Server Management Studio: Database Attachment Failed

Tags: database, iis, sql-server-2008

I have publish my website in IIS7. It is running in DefaultAppPool. The Identity of this app-pool is set to LocalSystem. The IIS is running and I can run the application from IIS without any problem.

Now I want to attach the database placed in inetpub's application folder:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EMSApplication\App_Data\ASPNETDB.mdf

I have added new logins in the SSMS which are: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool.

But when I am trying to attach that database in the SSMS I am getting follwoing error:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.)
>   while attempting to open or create the physical file
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EMSApplication\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF'. (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 5123)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.5500&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5123&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio works against a Parent Instance of SQL Express, not your User Instance. A user instance is a separate instance of the SQL Server Express Database Engine that is generated by a parent instance. User instances allow users who are not administrators on their local computers to attach and connect to SQL Server Express databases. Each instance runs under the security context of the individual user, on a one-instance-per-user basis. Here is a manual from msdn [How to connect to a User Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337276%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: If I stopped the IIS then I can attach that database. If the connection string is changed to Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.mdf;Database=C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\EMSAPPLICATION\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF;Trusted_Connection=Yes, then I can run the application and browse the database from ssms. But it fails to create new table. My application is managed by nhibernate and by this I am creating tables on application launch.

Comment: It seems that your IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool doesn't have permissions to create tables. Make it for example db_owner of your db.

Comment: I need to add full permission for the user: SqlServerMSSQLUser$MyComputerName$SQLEXPRESS to the App_Data directory and its sub-directory.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do that **running** Management Studio **As Administrator**.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.your .mdf and .ldf files don't have necessary permission.
you should add your windows account in both .mdf and .ldf files and give it full control permission.
Now you can attach your database successfully.